# Syntax error в запросе SQL на добавление записи

Tags: python, sql

Есть таблица `ttt` и в ней столбец с названием: `second (test)`. Вылетает синтаксическая ошибка: `Syntax Error` из-за скобки перед словом `test`.

Как правильно написать запрос SQL, чтобы добавить в этот столбец данные?

```
INSERT INTO ttt(first, second (test)) VALUES('{}', '{}')".format(...)
```

Ошибка:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(test)) VALUES(... at line 1
```

Таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
qry = """INSERT INTO ttt(first, `second (test)`) VALUES(%s, %s)"""
# NOTE: ------------------------^         ----^
cursor.execute(qry, [param1, param2])
```

**NOTE:** если у вас есть малейшая возможность переименовать столбец так, чтобы его наименование состояло только из букв английского алфавита и знака подчеркивания - настоятельно рекомендую ей воспользоваьтся! Это поможет избежать многих потенциальных проблем...